# How to combine the product when the same and when add in a list box?

Tags: c#, forms

How to combine the product when the same?
How to get the sum of the price?
If not the same a product it will add in a list box.
If the same the product it will combine and the sum of the price it will combine.

Here's the code about my program. ^_^;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string product = txtProduct.Text;
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text);

        lstProductPriceBox.Items.Add(
            product + " = " + price.ToString("c")); // How to combine the product when the same? and
                                                   //  How to get the sum of the price?
                                                   // If not the same product it will add in a list box
                                                   // if the same the product it will combine and sum the price.
    } 

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried in order to achieve both of your goals and where you are struggling so we can help you

Comment: My goal is when I add the product + " = " + price.ToString("c") in a list box. If the product will the same to my second add in a list box how to combine and the sum of the price?

Comment: Can you give some more examples of what you want to do mathematically, depending on what the product and price look like, and what your expected result will be in the list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Product class that contains a ProductName and a Price. Here's code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Product> source;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        source = new List<Product>();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal price;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProduct.Text) || !decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid values!");
            return;
        }
        var existingProduct = source.Where(x=> x.ProductName==txtProduct.Text).SingleOrDefault();
        if(existingProduct!=null)
        {
            existingProduct.Price += price; 
        }
        else
            source.Add(new Product {Price = price, ProductName = txtProduct.Text} );

        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = source;
    }

 }

public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} = {1}", ProductName, Price.ToString("c"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Paolo Costa thank you so much, your answer is far more accurate than SteveFerg. you help me a lot to both of you. @ Paolo Costa | @ SteveFerg thank you to both of you ); ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string product = txtProduct.Text;
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text);



        bool price_found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < lstProductPriceBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstProductPriceBox.Items[i].ToString().Contains(product + " ="))
            {
                string x = lstProductPriceBox.Items[i].ToString().Substring(lstProductPriceBox.Items[i].ToString().IndexOf("=") + 1).Replace("$","");
                decimal current_total = Convert.ToDecimal(x);
                lstProductPriceBox.Items[i] = product + " = " + (price +  current_total).ToString("c");
                price_found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!price_found)
            lstProductPriceBox.Items.Add(product + " = " + price.ToString("c"));
    }
```

Comment: And what happens when one of the products is named "frogs" and another is named "green frogs"?

Comment: Notice I search for the product name up to and including the equal sign. The assumption is that the product will not have an equal sign in the product name itself.

Comment: You mark the answer as accepted adds reputation. This forum is more about helping people than accumulating reputation (for me anyway). I have received great help from the answers people have posted. This is my way of giving back.

Comment: Well, the answer has the problems described by @PeterDuniho, please look at the other one I provided. It's better not to approve an incorrect answer as other people can have the same problem and maybe ending using the wrong code. Nothing personal with Steve of course :-)

Comment: Paolo Costa has provided and excellent solution. My solution is rather quick and short. Paolo's is more thorough and structured. Good work.